# The meaning of "point like an infant"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> ‘And I shall be left alone with George! But suppose it isn’t cured,’ said Miss Henschil of a sudden. ‘Suppose it comes back again. What can I do? I can’t send for him in this way when I’m a married woman!’ **She pointed like an infant.**

This is from "In the Same Boat " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/in-the-same-boat.htm

I don't understand the meaning of "pointed like an infant".

Comment: Hi, Hiroshi - is there a particular part that you don't understand?  Do you know the verb *to point*, and the meaning of the word *like*, and what *an infant* is?

Comment: *She said in a childlike manner* (but I am not sure)

Comment: Is "pointed" supposed to be "pouted"? I don't know why she would point.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I found a dozen copies of this story online, and they all say "pointed", including [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/13085/13085-h/13085-h.htm)

Comment: @gotube Thanks. In that case, I wonder whether Kipling really meant to use that word and, if so, whether it might have had a different meaning for him than it does for us.

Comment: Thank you for many suggestions given here.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning seems to be literal.  Small children will point at people in a way that [adults would find rude](https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/why-is-it-rude-to-point/#:%7E:text=In%20many%20cultures%2C%20including%20ours,them%20an%20object%20of%20scrutiny.).

In the story, Miss Henschill says "I can’t send for *him* in this way when I’m a married woman!" and as she does so she points at Mr Conroy.

Comment: James, thank you so much for giving me a new point of view. It seems possibly correct.